# Stuck at the last step in recreating the paper rotation effect done by FiftyThree

Tags: 3d

To see the final effect of the paper rotation :
[Paper By FiftyThree](http://vimeo.com/37254322)

You can see that at any point of rotation, only two sides are rotating. I have done up a bootstrap demo where the positioning of the papers are calculated: 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/colintoh/2EwfS/2/)

I'm basing this positioning on the assumption that the papers are actually lying on a triangle and the paper that are rotating are actually pivoting at the tip of the triangle.

[image: Front view of the papers]
[image: Bottom view of the papers]

As the papers shift along the x-axis, it is sliding along the triangle. You can check out the effect by sliding the slider in the demo. However, the two side of the paper must be rotating together in order to achieve the desired rotation effect. How do i find the correlation between shifting of x- positioning and the rotation angle of the rotating side?

Here are some points that I hope can help:

- The triangle formed by the two rotating side is isosceles at all times
- The angles of all sides except the two rotating side remains the same at all time. Only their (x,z) position is changed.